# Sub-setting data-frame with [] and $ and sample in R cause row duplicated

Tags: r, subset, sample

I plan to use `sample` function to randomly subset a data.frame.
My original approach is

```
data(mtcars)
mtcarsDF<-data.frame(mtcars,stringsAsFactors =F)
mtcarsDF$Name<-row.names(mtcarsDF)
mtcarsDF$Test<-F
mtcarsDF[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3),]$Test<-T
table(mtcarsDF$Test)
```

The number of `Test==F` and `Test==T` is 2:1. It seems correct. However, I found that some rows in the data.frame `mtcarsDF` are randomly duplicated.

```
sort(table(mtcarsDF$Name))
```

In the original dataset, `Toyota Corolla` only appears in one row. After `mtcarsDF[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3),]$Test<-T`, the rows are messed up.

```
    AMC Javelin  Cadillac Fleetwood          Camaro Z28          Datsun 710    Dodge Challenger 
              1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
       Fiat 128           Fiat X1-9        Lotus Europa       Mazda RX4 Wag           Merc 240D 
              1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
  Porsche 914-2       Toyota Corona             Valiant          Volvo 142E          Duster 360 
              1                   1                   1                   1                   2 
    Honda Civic      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout Lincoln Continental       Maserati Bora 
              2                   2                   2                   2                   2 
      Mazda RX4           Merc 280C      Toyota Corolla 
              2                   2                   2
```

If I **save the sample index in a variable** `testIndex` first, then do the same subset process. I can get the correct results.

```
mtcarsDF<-data.frame(mtcars,stringsAsFactors =F)
mtcarsDF$Name<-row.names(mtcarsDF)
mtcarsDF$Test<-F
testIndex<-sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3)
mtcarsDF[testIndex,]$Test<-T
```

Result:

```
        AMC Javelin  Cadillac Fleetwood          Camaro Z28   Chrysler Imperial          Datsun 710 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
   Dodge Challenger          Duster 360        Ferrari Dino            Fiat 128           Fiat X1-9 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
     Ford Pantera L         Honda Civic      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout Lincoln Continental 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
       Lotus Europa       Maserati Bora           Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag            Merc 230 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
          Merc 240D            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE          Merc 450SL 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
        Merc 450SLC    Pontiac Firebird       Porsche 914-2      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
            Valiant          Volvo 142E 
                  1                   1
```

I cannot understand exactly what causes the differences. I also try the other approach:

```
mtcarsDF<-data.frame(mtcars,stringsAsFactors =F)
mtcarsDF$Name<-row.names(mtcarsDF)
mtcarsDF$Test<-F
mtcarsDF[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3),"Test"]<-T
sort(table(mtcarsDF$Name))
```

The results are correct, too.

```
        AMC Javelin  Cadillac Fleetwood          Camaro Z28   Chrysler Imperial          Datsun 710 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
   Dodge Challenger          Duster 360        Ferrari Dino            Fiat 128           Fiat X1-9 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
     Ford Pantera L         Honda Civic      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout Lincoln Continental 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
       Lotus Europa       Maserati Bora           Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag            Merc 230 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
          Merc 240D            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE          Merc 450SL 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
        Merc 450SLC    Pontiac Firebird       Porsche 914-2      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona 
                  1                   1                   1                   1                   1 
            Valiant          Volvo 142E 
                  1                   1
```

I'm not sure why only **sample() + $ approach** messes up the data. That would be great if someone can share the reason of it.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Try with `mtcarsDF$Test[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3)] <- TRUE`

Comment: That works! May I know what's the differences between `mtcarsDF$Test[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3)] <- TRUE` and `mtcarsDF[sample(1:nrow(mtcarsDF), nrow(mtcarsDF)/3),]$Test<-T` ?

Comment: In your case, you are subsetting the dataset first and then extract the column and assign it.  The way I showed is to extract the column, subset it and assign